# Generating set of General linear group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, general-linear-group

What is one possible minimal [generating set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group) of the [general linear group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group) $GL_{m}(Z_{p})$?

It might be very easy question whose solution is known to everyone except me. Kindly help me with the same.

Edit: For example,

Consider the group $GL_2(Z_{2})$, is non abelian group of order 6, i.e., $GL_2(Z_{2}) \cong S_3$ and the set $\Big\{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \Big\}$ generates $GL_2(Z_{2})$.

Comment: What exactly do mean when you ask "what are generators"? Are you asking for an example of a generating set? Also, do you expecting an answer that is very different from what you would get for $GL_m(\Bbb R)$?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/99236/8157) should be related, if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: You have changed the question and added "minimal generating set". But be careful, a group can have several minimal generating sets of different cardinality, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2792575/how-is-minimal-generating-set-of-a-group-defined-whats-the-algorithm-to-find-i?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

One set of generators for $GL(n,q)$ with $q\neq 2$ is given by
$$
A(\xi)={\rm diag}(\xi,1,1,\ldots ,1), \quad B= \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \cr -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & -1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \cr & & \ddots \cr 0 & 0 &\ldots  & -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$